# Best nodejs and docker deployment strategy

Tags: node.js, docker

Currently I’m doing DevOps for a NodeJS project. I’m using Pm2 as nodejs process manager to deploy the application, but I’m considering switch to Docker. In this direction I’m thinking in what is the best deployment strategy to deploy the application.

1. First I think in create a docker image for the application, and do the app update tasks within that image. That wouldn’t require to create another docker image everytime we update the app.
2. But, I think option number 1 conflicts directly with microservice philosophy. So I think follow microservice philosophy means that every app update requires a new microservice version, so we have to construct a new docker image version every time we update the app.

I would like to know what’s the best approach for you, why and what tools to use for automate new images building in the deployment process.

Thanks.

Comment: What's best for us may not the best for you. Also, "best" is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Federkun my intention is to open a debate so the members can expose their opinions. That way I probably can build my own opinion based on other users experiences.

Comment: I understand, and it would be a nice debate to have - problem is that this kind of discussion here is off-topic. This is more suited for reddit, maybe?

Comment: Mmm, I was thinking more in technical opinions like the one of @stuart wikefield’s. I don’t think this kind of technical discussion is an off-topic, but if it is, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I tend to organise my Docker deployments are as follows:

```
docker/
  base/
    Dockerfile
  build/
    Dockerfile
Dockerfile
package.json
...
```

Firstly create a base image Docker image, this includes any dependencies that are common to both build and runtime so that these layers are reused between the two Docker images:

```
# docker/base/Dockerfile
FROM node:9.5-alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add ...
```

From the base Docker image create a build Docker image containing the build-time specific tools and dependencies and the CMD triggers the build process:

```
# docker/build/Dockerfile
FROM app-base:1.0
RUN apk --no-cache add ...
VOLUME ["/var/workspace"]
WORKDIR /var/workspace
CMD ["npm", "install"]
```

Then your application can be built each time by running it in the `app-build` image. I normally output a tarball containing all of the built dependencies ready to run this way it is simple to inject the whole application into a new Docker image.

Finally package up the application in a docker image, this contains only the production dependencies and the users and groups set up for running the application and will pick up the tarball that was output from the build step, i.e.:

```
FROM app-base:1.0
ARG version=latest
ARG user=app
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
RUN apk --no-cache add ... && useradd ...
ADD app-${version}.tar.gz /usr/share/app
WORKDIR /usr/share/app
USER ${user}
CMD ["node", "/usr/share/app/index.js"]
```

I build it in a Docker image so that I don't introduce incompatibilities from building it directly from the host and I use a separate Docker image from the production image so that I don't have extra stuff in my production image, which helps reduce the size when transferring the Docker image and reduces the surface area for security. YMMV and this is just one way to do it.

I haven't yet looked into [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) yet but it looks like an interesting option.

**Update**

Some of the teams I have been in started with single Docker image that has an entrypoint script that installs the app and its dependencies but eventually moved away because they were relying on resources on the network that happened to not be there (repositories down) when they needed to deploy critical changes.

However, some teams I've been in have continued that approach for the reason they didn't consider the Docker image the main artifact. Their image downloaded the packaged application, config and secrets and they made sure all dependencies were hosted on repositories within their network and their control.

Comment: Very interesting solution. As I can see, maybe there are as many solutions as administrators. I’m wondering if my first option, the one that mantains a container that simply updates the application code is a good approach.

Comment: There's no reason why that wouldn't work but possibly some things to consider... I'll update my answer.